# Fetch Tag\Element value of XML from CLOB in DB2 database

Tags: sql, xml, db2, clob

i have an xml of the following structue...

Structure of XML:

```
<Persons>
    <PersonID>12345</Person>
    <PersonName>Larissa</Person>
    <PersonAge>28</Person>
<Persons>

<Persons>
    <PersonID>12345</Person>
    <PersonName>Larissa</Person>
    <PersonAge>28</Person>
<Persons>
```

The xml is in the CLOB datatype column of IBM DB2 Database.I want to fire an select query to extract the value of **PersonID** field and get the value 12345 in return.

Is there any functions in DB2 for xml by using which i can extract the value of the PersonID???

Comment: <Persons>
<PersonlD>12345</Person>
<Per sonNane >LarissaQPerson>
<PersonAge>28</Person>
</Persons>

Comment: I'm wondering why you close your `<PersonName>` with `</Person>` instead of `</PersonName>`. Beside that I never see an opening tag of `<Person>`.

Comment: Sorry Shegit..its my mistake...i mannualy created the xml....i just want to extract value of a element from xml...can you suggest some solutions?

Comment: Sorry soumitra, I've never used XML nor DB2 nor CLOB. As far as I heard and read, XML requires the same closing tag as opening tag. Is your solution a valid XML-document? And did you look up some questions that pops up on right side of your question as related?

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: I stumbled upon this, as I have same scenario. Did you find a solution for this? You have not marked the only answer below as solution but I am thinking that won't work since the column type is CLOB not XML.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming DB2 Linux/Unix/Window)

You can [use xquery](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0604saracco/) to get the results you want:

```
xquery
db2-fn:xmlcolumn('YOUR_TABLE.YOUR_COLUMN')/Persons/PersonID/text()
```

Since this query invokes xquery directly, you have to instruct DB2 to use the xquery parser (instead of the SQL parser) by using the `xquery` keyword.